# How to create a String instead of printing it to standard out?

Tags: rust

Consider the following function:

```
use std::io;

pub fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, How are you doing? What's your characters name?");

    let mut name = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Failed to read name. What was that name again?");

    println!("Welcome to the castle {}", name);
}
```

How do I take the last `println!` and turn it into a `"Welcome to the castle {}".to_string();` and have the `{}` replaced with `name` (obviously I would need to add `-> String` to the function declaration.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.format!.html) macro.

```
pub fn hello() -> String {
    println!("Hello, How are you doing? What's your characters name?");

    let mut name = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Failed to read name. What was that name again?");

    format!("Welcome to the castle {}", name)
}
```